# Can I custom TextField suffixIcon with background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the text field search icon (suffix) to have a green background, then my text field using shadow not border. Can u help me with this? or this one cannot implement in flutter?

Here my code:

```
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 0,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    ),
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                  hintText: "Bandung, Jawa Barat",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black45),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  prefixIcon: Image.asset('assets/img/map.png', height: 15),
                  suffixIcon: Image.asset('assets/img/search.png', color: Colors.green),
                  
                  suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: 50,
                  )
                ),
              )
```

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: I have updated my code. Take a look. Hope it helps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain shadow for your `TextField` widget, one option is `Material` widget. Wrap your `Textfield` with `Material` widget which has properties like `elevation`, `shadowColor`, `borderRadius`. It is cleaner option for shadow than `Container` widget which has property `decoration`.

**Output**

[image]

**Copy paste this below code to see the effect:**

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomTextField State createState() => _CustomTextField State();
}

class _CustomTextField State extends State<CustomTextField > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 25),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    shadowColor: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      autofocus: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search here',
                          hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black45),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: true,
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.green),
                          suffixIcon: Material(
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            shadowColor: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3.0))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is possible to add background color to the suffix (search icon)?

Comment: @RLovanto Yeah. I guess. `sufficIcon` property takes widget which means you can customise it as you like. If it helps, you can accept this answer and upvote so that it can help others as well